# Access Window property from UserControl child

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, user-controls, window

I have a MainWindow with a TabControl. Each Tab is a UserControl existing in a different file.

```
...
<TabControl>
   <TabItem>
      <local:Tab1>
   </TabItem>
...
   <TabItem>
      <local:Tab2>
   </TabItem>
</TabControl>
```

These UserControls should act different depending on the access rights. The access rights (an int) are passed to the Main Window after the login screen via:

```
MainWindow mainWindow = new MainWindow(accessRights);
mainWindow.show();
```

Now I have the access rights in the MainWindow.xaml.cs. But how can I access these access rights in the UserControls.

Comment: What about creating a `UserManagement` class with a static instance and then let your `UserControl` and any other controls, classes grab the `int` from this instance?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could add a dependency property to each `UserControl` class:

```
public class Tab1 : UserControl
{
    ...

    public Boolean HasAccess
    {
        get { return (Boolean)this.GetValue(HasAccessProperty); }
        set { this.SetValue(HasAccessProperty, value); }
    }
    public static readonly DependencyProperty HasAccessProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
      "HasAccess", typeof(Boolean), typeof(Tab1), new PropertyMetadata(false));
}
```

...and bind it to a public property of the parent window in your XAML markup:

```
<TabControl>
    <TabItem>
        <local:Tab1 HasAccess="{Binding Path=WindowProperty, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Window}}" />
    </TabItem>
    ...
</TabControl>
```

**How to: Implement a Dependency Property:** https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms750428(v=vs.110).aspx

Make sure that the window class exposes the access right(s) using a *public property* because you cannot bind to fields.

The other option would be to get a reference to the parent window using the `Window.GetWindow` method in the code-behind of the `UserControl` once it has been loaded:

```
public partial class MyUserControl : UserControl
{
    public MyUserControl()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Loaded += (s, e) => 
        {
            MainWindow parentWindow = Window.GetWindow(this) as MainWindow;
            if(parentWindow != null)
            {
                //access property of the MainWindow class that exposes the access rights...
            }
        };
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add this logic to your User-Controls:

```
MainWindow mw = (MainWindow)this.Parent;
accessRights = mw.accessRights;
```

This is the logic and you may need to change above code to match syntax etc.

Comment: When I use this in the UserControl constructor the mw reference is always null.

Comment: The child UserControl contructors are called first and then the parent, so move the above logic to non constructor method in the UserControls.

Answer (score 0):

Pass a reference of your MainWindow instance to the constructor of your UserControl instances while creating them. By doing this you gain access to public properties of your containing main form in the UserControls code.

Comment: But I create the UserControl instances in the xaml. How can I pass the reference then?

Comment: Ooops, missed the WPF part ;-)   
So maybe you can use `Window parentWindow = Window.GetWindow(this);` in your UserControl to access the containing main window.

Answer (score 0):

Try with EventAggregator from Prism.Core, Basicly u set Publish method where you pass your int and in that user control Subscribe to that event, event will be in your case Window loaded.

MainWindowViewModel

```
   public MainWindowViewModel( IEventAggregator eventAggregator)
    {
        eventAggregator.GetEvent<PassingIntToUserControlEvent>().Publish(HereGoesYourInt);
    }
```

UserControlViewModel

```
 public UserControlViewModel( IEventAggregator eventAggregator)
    {
        eventAggregator.GetEvent<PassingIntToUserControlEvent>().Subscribe(SomeMethodYouWantWithYourInt);
    }
```

and to set that PassingIntToUserControlEvent is so easy.

```
public class PassingIntToUserControlEvent : PubSubEvent<int>{}
```

and your set to go.

This video has basic introdction to Prism and some of it's component, one of them is EventAggregator. I've found it to be very usefull. Hope it helps.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZfBy2nfykqY